# Mutual exclusiveness in multiple observations (panel data) in Stata

Tags: stata

I have multiple observations with different  exposures and am using Stata/MP 16.1. I would like to group `exposure` by `id` depending on whether the exposure is mutually exclusive or not. Please see the data example.

The desired variable is `groups` which I  made manually. Since the dataset contains >100,000 observations,  how can I implement by code for the desired variable `groups`?

```
* Example generated by -dataex-. To install: ssc install dataex
clear
input float id str1 exposure long groups
1 "." 2
1 "a" 2
1 "a" 2
2 "a" 1
2 "." 1
2 "b" 1
2 "c" 1
3 "a" 1
3 "c" 1
3 "c" 1
4 "b" 3
4 "b" 3
4 "b" 3
end
label values groups groups
label def groups 1 "not mutually exclusive", modify
label def groups 2 "only a", modify
label def groups 3 "only b", modify
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
 * Example generated by -dataex-. To install: ssc install dataex
    clear
    input float id str1 exposure long groups
    1 "a" 2
    1 "a" 2
    1 "a" 2
    2 "a" 1
    2 "a" 1
    2 "b" 1
    2 "c" 1
    3 "a" 1
    3 "c" 1
    3 "c" 1
    4 "b" 3
    4 "b" 3
    4 "b" 3
    end
    label values groups groups
    label def groups 1 "not mutually exclusive", modify
    label def groups 2 "only a", modify
    label def groups 3 "only b", modify
    
    bysort id (exposure) : gen wanted = cond(exposure[1] != exposure[_N], 1, cond(exposure[1] == "a", 2, cond(exposure[1] == "b", 3, .)))
    label val wanted groups 

    assert wanted == groups
```

The logic is that

if there are different values within an `id`, assign 1

otherwise, the values are the same; so

assign 2 if the first value is `a` (equivalently all values are `a`)

assign 3 if the first value is `b` (equivalently all values are `b`)

otherwise assign missing -- there shouldn't be any such according to your example, but checking is a good idea.

Naturally you can break that down into shorter statements:

```
bysort id (exposure) : gen wanted = 1 if exposure[1] != exposure[_N] 
by id: replace wanted = 2 if exposure[1] == "a" 
by id: replace wanted = 3 if exposure[2] == "b"
```

EDIT Here is some technique more complicated set-ups. Note that Stata doesn't attach any special meaning to `"."`.

```
* Example generated by -dataex-. To install: ssc install dataex
clear
input float id str1 exposure long groups
1 "." 2
1 "a" 2
1 "a" 2
2 "a" 1
2 "." 1
2 "b" 1
2 "c" 1
3 "a" 1
3 "c" 1
3 "c" 1
4 "b" 3
4 "b" 3
4 "b" 3
end

label values groups groups
label def groups 1 "not mutually exclusive", modify
label def groups 2 "only a", modify
label def groups 3 "only b", modify
label def groups 4 "only c", modify

gen OK = exposure != "."
sort OK id exposure 
by OK id: gen wanted = 1 if OK & exposure[1] != exposure[_N] 
by OK id: replace wanted = 2 if wanted == . & OK & exposure[1] == "a"
by OK id: replace wanted = 3 if wanted == . & OK & exposure[1] == "b"
by OK id: replace wanted = 4 if wanted == . & OK & exposure[1] == "c"

bysort id (exposure OK) : replace wanted = wanted[_N]
drop OK 
label val wanted groups 

list, sepby(id)

     +-----------------------------------------------------------------+
     | id   exposure                   groups                   wanted |
     |-----------------------------------------------------------------|
  1. |  1          .                   only a                   only a |
  2. |  1          a                   only a                   only a |
  3. |  1          a                   only a                   only a |
     |-----------------------------------------------------------------|
  4. |  2          .   not mutually exclusive   not mutually exclusive |
  5. |  2          a   not mutually exclusive   not mutually exclusive |
  6. |  2          b   not mutually exclusive   not mutually exclusive |
  7. |  2          c   not mutually exclusive   not mutually exclusive |
     |-----------------------------------------------------------------|
  8. |  3          a   not mutually exclusive   not mutually exclusive |
  9. |  3          c   not mutually exclusive   not mutually exclusive |
 10. |  3          c   not mutually exclusive   not mutually exclusive |
     |-----------------------------------------------------------------|
 11. |  4          b                   only b                   only b |
 12. |  4          b                   only b                   only b |
 13. |  4          b                   only b                   only b |
     +-----------------------------------------------------------------+
```

Comment: I did not think about missing in the exposure data. For eg,  I would like to group "id" 1 as "only a"even if the first observation is missing. So, I have revised the data. [CODE]
* Example generated by -dataex-. To install: ssc install dataex
clear
input float id str1 exposure long groups
1 "." 2
1 "a" 2
1 "a" 2
2 "a" 1
2 "." 1
2 "b" 1
2 "c" 1
3 "a" 1
3 "c" 1
3 "c" 1
4 "b" 3
4 "b" 3
4 "b" 3
end
label values groups groups
label def groups 1 "not mutually exclusive", modify
label def groups 2 "only a", modify
label def groups 3 "only b", modify
[/CODE]

Comment: Posting lengthy code in comments rarely helps; it is too hard to read. As a detail, note from `help dataex` that the annotations `[CODE] [/CODE]` are mark-up for Statalist and not needed here.  You can edit your question, but leave the original question and mark new material with something like EDIT.

Comment: Thanks Nick. My apology for that. Now I understand not to post codes as Statalist. I have edited the example data in the question.

Comment: OK, so does `a` and missing count the same to you as just `a`? SImilarly `b` and missing as compared with `b`?

Comment: Yes, for `id` 1, I would like to assume as `only a` despite missing. Same as for `b`. For `id` 2  which also includes missing, I would like to assume as `not mutually exclusive` as `id` 2 has different types of exposures.